# Refund a Transaction REST does not accept last 4 cc number

Tags: rest

According to the API Doc [1](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-refund-a-transaction):
*When issuing a credit card refund, the request must include either a full card number and expiration date, or the original transaction ID (transId) and last 4 digits of the card number.*

I assume the original transaction ID should be provided as '**refTransId**'

But even with the refTransId provided, the API still returns this messsage.

```js
 "errors": [
            {
                "errorCode": "6",
                "errorText": "The credit card number is invalid."
            }
        ]
```

When provided with full CC number and expiration date, the refund is processed successfully. Any idea why?

Comment: This isn't a rest issue, but is a functional error specific to this API's logic.  You'll likely do better by reaching out to the API's vendor's support team https://developer.authorize.net/support.html or using their forums: https://community.developer.cybersource.com/t5/Integration-and-Testing/bd-p/Integration01

Comment: May be relevant (I just did a quick search and skim of the answer; I don't know this API so can't say too much).  https://community.developer.cybersource.com/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Refund-transaction-error-code-quot-6-quot-and-error-message-quot/m-p/54306#M29310